# Retrieving hidden URL for an image (Image with no attachment, url only)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I have made a small code, which would retrieve a random message (in that case an image) from a specified channel. Then it would get the URL of the image (in some cases it would be an attachment, which works with message.attachments.url).

Problem is, that Discord automatically hides the URLs and shows only an image. It is not an attachment but a link which is being hidden from message.content, so the content returns nothing/empty message.

Here is the code:

```
@Client.command()
async def pfp(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    pfp_ch = Client.get_channel(int(pfp_id)) # PFP_id was provided in the beginning of the file
    collection = (await pfp_ch.history(limit=200, oldest_first=True).flatten())
    tosend = random.choice(collection)
    try:
        await ctx.send(tosend.attachments.url)
    except:
        # Here needed: Retrieval
        await ctx.send(tosend.content)
        # Where content should be: "https://media.tenor.com/images/someimageshere/somegif.gif"
```

Error received when using await ctx.send(tosend.content):

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

Basically, how could I get the URL of an image added as a URL, not as attachment?

Answer (score 0):

The `collection` list is empty, you might not have the reading message history permission or have any messages in the channel.